# Getting errors in Package hyfo in terms of bias correction of time series and not nc data

Tags: r

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Input dataset is incorrect, it should contain "Data", "xyCoords", and "Dates",
check help for details or use loadNCDF to read NetCDF file.

If time series input is needed, and your input is a time series, please put "TS = yourinput".

trying to apply a bias correction to rainfall forecasts but keep getting this error, My data is a time series with four columns (Date, Observed, Hindcast, Forecast). i donot know how to let r know that my data is a time series. New to R.

Answer (score 0):

install package hyfo, then follow these steps;

```
library(hyfo)
bb <-biasCorrect(Forecast,hindcast,observation,method="gqm",preci = TRUE)
```

> NB:method of bias correction varies depending with the researcher
>   preference i.e eqm,scaling,delta etc.
>
> Date format is mostly the problem,u put is as; 2019-2-1